# RSA Digital Signature Verification

Tags: android, rsa, chilkat

Does any know how to use CHILKAT in android for RSA Digital Signature Verification ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.example-code.com/android/rsa_generateKeyAndSign.asp                                               http://www.cknotes.com/?p=283 
This links are the solution......

Comment: This link is for generating public and private key for signing data.
I already got the same. I want to verify the signature with public key using CHILKAT....